# How can child component access actions of parent component in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

I have made up a system where child components are generated dynamically according to some variable. But, all the possible components share some method. How can this be achieved ?

**Parent component:**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    someAction() {}
  }
});
```

*In the parent view, component is called using the {{component}} helper*

`{{component 'someComponent'}}`

**Child component:**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({});
```

Here i need to access the someAction in parent component in the child view.

eg:

```
<button {{action 'someAction'}}>Click me !!</button>
```

I am using Ember 1.13.0

Answer (score 3):

You need to give the action down:

```
{{component 'someComponent' someAction=(action 'someAction')}}
```

And then call it in your child component:

```
this.attrs['someAction']();
```

You can put this on a common mixin:

```
actions: {
  someAction() {
    this.attrs['someAction'](...arguments);
  }
}
```